# Templated Linear Search

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, linear-search

Implement a function called find that takes in the following as parameters (in this order):

The object we want to find within the array
A dynamic array of ANY type
The size of the array
This function should look within the array for the element specified and return the index position of the element. If the element does not exist, the function should return -1.

The code that I have is:

```
template<typename t>
t find(t objectInArray, t *array, int arraySize)
{
   array = new t[arraySize];

   for(int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++){
      if(array[index] == objectInArray){
         cout << index;
         return index;
       }
   }
     return -1;
}
```

I ran this code in main using int, without the template and it works perfectly. I'm actually puzzled what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Also, 1) why are you returning `-1`?  What if the type you're searching for is `std::string`?  That `-1` return value will not compile.  2) why are you using `new[]`, thus creating a memory leak?

Comment: To add, [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)  does this already for you.

Comment: I changed my return type of the function     `t` to     `int`. I'm suppose to return index if the object is in the array, else i'm suppose to return -1 if the object is not in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-assign the pointer. Delete this line.

```
array = new t[arraySize];
```

What you want to return is an index. So the return type should not be `t`. Return an integer type.

---

Side note:

You are probably told by your teacher or your book to create dynamic array using `new` expression. You may have written one in your main function. I have to point out that is against the general advise in the community due to the danger of memory leak although students usually do not have a choice. If a `new` has to be used, remember to give it a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: The call to `new` is a memory leak in the OP's code.  It shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess adding a side note addressing it would be fine.

Comment: If i take out the line `array = new t[arraySize];` how would i be able to use to for loop to go through all the elements in the array?

Comment: @hicu0 Do you know what does that line do?